# phpThumb- version 2003- How do I sort images on Linux

Tags: image, sorting, phpthumb

I originally tested this software on a Windows 2000 server. The problem I have now is that it has been ported to a hosting company that uses Linux. The images were stored numerically as in: 00.jpg/01/jpg/02.jpg etc. These were sorted AND displayed in this order by the software on the Windows server (www.especialesalba.com). Once ported to Linux the sorting has now become different – random it appears (www.luzdelsol.co.uk).

The techies tell me that the sorting on both OSs are the same & could not answer the fact that if the software has not been touch at all (only the directory pointings etc in config) then why are they sorted differently. They did however say that they had found a call to an `arraySortByColumn` and references to argument: `SORT_DESC` & `SORT_ASC`. I cannot for the life of me find these using a search in a text editor. I have asked them to tell me where they saw these & am still waiting.

Please can anyone tell me where I can change the sort orders of images or where/what is affecting the sort order in Linux?